Upgrading from Nifi 2.0.0-M4 to Nifi-2.0.0
I had installed Nifi Registry and Nifi 2.0.0-M4 (it was latest version then), and I have implemented lots of flows there.
Now I want to upgrade my Nifi and Nifi Registry to 2.0.0, what is the easiest way to that?
I have multiple buckets, flows,... so importing exporting one by one is not easy, by the way I have lots of parameter contexts, and global services (which seems are not stored in registry).
What is the easiest way to do the migration?
